# Access DB: Add new column of row number within group

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, window-functions

I want to add a new column in access Db to put the order.

I want to know the query that sequentially increases or decreases by creating a column called Num based on the key1 column as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Can you have duplicate values?  If so, what would the results be?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend actually storing this derived information. Instead, you can compute it on the fly whenever neede - in MS Access, where window functions are not available, the simplest approach might be a correlated subquery.

If you are going to use this on a regular basis, you could create a view:

```
create view myview as
select 
    key, 
    value1,
    1 + (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.key = t.key and t1.value < t.value) num
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT Count(*)
            from Table1 as t2
            WHERE (t2.value1 <= t.value1 AND t2.key1 = t.key1)
            ) AS Num
FROM Table1 AS t;
```

[image]